# Creating an entity with a reference to an other entity in azure mobile service

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, ef-code-first, azure-mobile-services

I've created a azure mobile service which basically consist of 2 Entities and 2 TableControllers. Those both entities have a 1:1 relation.

```
public class Entity1 : EntityData
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Entity2 Reference { get; set; }
}

public class Entity2 : EntityData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The controllers are the standard scaffold generated controllers. When I'm try to insert a  entity1 instance with a reference to a already existing entity2 i get the following message:

```
{"$id":"1","message":"The operation failed due to a conflict: 'Violation of 
PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Service.Entity2'. Cannot insert
duplicate key in object 'Service.Entity2'. The duplicate key
value is (32aec44a282e42b7bc51096052335dad).\r\nThe statement has been 
terminated.'."}
```

I used the following JSON in the request body:

```
{
  "value": 1,
  "date": "2015-04-27T06:51:47.641Z",
  "name": "name",
  "project": {
    "id": "32aec44a282e42b7bc51096052335dad",
  }
}
```

Is it possible to use an already existing entity as a reference in .NET Code First/Azure Mobile Service? I'm not quite sure if this is a more EF CodeFirst or azure mobile service related question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behavior is for the insert of Entity1 to also attempt an insert of the nested Reference. If that value has already been inserted, then a conflict such as this could occur.

One option would be to modify the insert code to treat the nested item as already inserted, as in the "Attaching an existing entity to the context" section of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx

For more, this blog post might be helpful:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2014/06/18/insert-update-related-data-with-1-n-relationship-using-net-backend-azure-mobile-services.aspx

Comment: So, do you know if this is the same for Updates? I am getting the same problem with an Patch/Update when the object includes related data. I have a Profile which has a collection of phone numbers. When I update the profile on the mobile device and push the changes to azure, I get the same 409 conflict saying it cant insert the phone numbers because they exist already. Why is it trying to insert the related data on an update/patch? What can I override to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

We were trying to do the same thing, but didn't care about updating the related entities themselves. If you want to update an entity that contains references to related entities, you can just attach them to the context and you won't get any PK Violation errors:

[image]